AWS ECS EC2 without loadbalancer?
I am deploying Nginx as a service/task on AWS ECS with EC2, and I've run into an issue where I cannot connect to the Nginx welcome page via its public IP address. I can access that by using loadBalancer but I don't want to use it.
Is there anyway I can deploy ECS task defination to ECS-EC2 and access it by using ipV4?
Here's a breakdown of my setup and what I've checked:

ECS Configuration:

I've set up ECS with an EC2 instance and defined a task definition for Nginx. The task is running according to the ECS console, and I can see the logs working there.


Docker and Nginx Container Status:

The Docker container for Nginx is active, and the port mapping is 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp


Security Group and Network ACLs:

The security group associated with the EC2 instance allows all inbound traffic on port 80.
Network ACLs also permit both inbound and outbound traffic on this port.


Internal Connectivity Test:

Using curl http://localhost and http://127.0.0.1 from within the EC2 instance isn't displays the Nginx welcome page.



I am unable to access it using the public IP. This issue persists even though everything seems configured properly.
Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated!

What network mode have you selected for the ECS task? And what are the port mappings of the ECS task? Adding the task definition JSON to your question would be helpful.

Thank, I used bridge network in task definition and open a port 80  in SG rather than allowing All traffic inbound rule.
